# How Does MachineKey.Protect Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cryptography

In the official description of the method, Microsoft explains in the following link that MachineKey.Protect "protects the specified data by encrypting **or** signing it": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx

What does it mean? How does it decide to encrypt, sign or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [.NET Web Development and Tools Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/10/22/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-1/) don't tell exactly how this works, but [this article](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/21/use-the-machinekey-api-to-protect-values-in-asp-net/) mentions that the MachineKey API does both operations (which is more secure, by the way).

I went a little deeper on .NET Reference Source, and apparently this is true. Check out this piece of code:

```
using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = encryptionAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor()) {
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
        cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // At this point:
        // memStream := IV || Enc(Kenc, IV, clearData)

        // These KeyedHashAlgorithm instances are single-use; we wrap it in a 'using' block.
        using (KeyedHashAlgorithm signingAlgorithm = _cryptoAlgorithmFactory.GetValidationAlgorithm()) {
            // Initialize the algorithm with the specified key
            signingAlgorithm.Key = _validationKey.GetKeyMaterial();

            // Compute the signature
            byte[] signature = signingAlgorithm.ComputeHash(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memStream.Length);

            // At this point:
            // memStream := IV || Enc(Kenc, IV, clearData)
            // signature := Sign(Kval, IV || Enc(Kenc, IV, clearData))

            // Append the signature to the encrypted payload
            memStream.Write(signature, 0, signature.Length);

            // At this point:
            // memStream := IV || Enc(Kenc, IV, clearData) || Sign(Kval, IV || Enc(Kenc, IV, clearData))

            // Algorithm complete
            byte[] protectedData = memStream.ToArray();
            return protectedData;
        }
    }
}
```

This is from the NetFXCryptoService, which is the default crypto provider in case you didn't configure a [DataProtector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection)

Answer (score 0):

From the first paragraph in the remarks section of the same page

> This method supersedes the Encode method, which requires the caller to specify whether the plaintext data should be encrypted, signed, or both. The Protect method performs the appropriate operation and securely protects the data.

What it is trying to say is depending on what you passed in to the `purposes` parameter it will change what operation `Protect` will do. You will need to look into the documentation further to see what purposes do which actions. Which strings do what actions depend on the [Protected Configuration Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2.aspx) you are using for your site.